# NodeJS jsmodbus package - readHoldingRegisters: float number expected

Tags: node.js, modbus-tcp

I'm using the jsmodbus package to access a TCP Modbus server to read the register 126 (Modbus number 40126), which is a signed 16-bit binary number.

With the following code, I'm getting the results below in the ReadHoldingRegistersResponseBody. I'm receiving 10 while expecting to see 10.1; How can I make it return a float number instead of an int?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
    // create a tcp modbus client
let Modbus = require("jsmodbus");
let net = require("net");
let socket = new net.Socket();
let client = new Modbus.client.TCP(socket);
let options = {
  host: "xxxxxx",
  port: xxxx
};

socket.on("connect", function() {
  client
    .readHoldingRegisters(125,1)
    .then(function(resp) {
      console.log(resp.response._body);
      socket.end();
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.error(
        require("util").inspect(arguments, {
          depth: null
        })
      );
      socket.end();
    });
});

socket.on("error", console.error);
socket.connect(options);
```

Result:

```
ReadHoldingRegistersResponseBody { _fc: 3, _byteCount: 2, _values: [ 10 ], _bufferLength: 4, _valuesAsArray: [ 10 ], _valuesAsBuffer: <Buffer 00 0a> }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modbus transfers registers of 16bit size and floating point numbers are represented either as 32bit or 64bit size buffers. So if floating point is required you have to at least catch two registers for example readHoldingRegisters(125, 2) and then work with the response buffer response.valuesAsBuffer.readFloat32BE(0).

I contacted the development team responsible for the modbus server I'm accessing and they told me that the decimal part of the numbers is not available in the modbus server. So I can't do much in this case, but it helped me to learn more.